# Why do Partner Developer Edition orgs only have two (2) licenses?

Tags: licenses, partner-portal, support, org, data-storage

In my day-to-day work, I'm used to spinning up Partner Developer Edition orgs for test and development of managed and unmanaged packages.

I thought [Partner Developer Edition](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Partner_Development_%26_Test_Environments) came with 20 seats, but now I get 2. Did I do something naughty?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I asked support nicely for more licenses for the developer org, which they kindly granted, along with:

> Partner Developer Edition orgs do come with 20 Salesforce licenses. However due to our new release, a minor bug has caused our Partner Developer Edition orgs to be created with only 2 licenses.
>
> We should have this fixed by early March.
>
> In the meantime, I have manually provisioned an additional 18 Salesforce licenses to the org.

Thank you Salesforce! (Case Number 10249110)

Comment: Ah - for ages, I would always get Partner Orgs with only 5mb of data instead of the 250 you get with Partner Orgs - spent my life raising cases...at least that seems to be fixed now, but I would also check that is still correct...

Comment: FWIW am getting 250MB recently @BritishBoyinDC

Comment: My Consulting Org mysteriously lacks Service Cloud User license & recently created Partner Developer org lacks 'Lice Agent'. Looks like bug is bigger than just that.

Comment: @user320 we didn't raise a case.

Comment: @Ganesh raise a case man!